# Spring Data Elastic Search @Query @Highlight

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

I can't get the highlighted fields with this query code, any thought on it, I'm using 
 SDE4.0.0.RC2, i want to use @Query:

```
@Query("{\n" +
           "  \"multi_match\": {\n" +
           "    \"query\": \"?0\",\n" +
           "    \"fields\": [\n" +
           "      \"code^2\",\n" +
           "      \"name\"\n" +
           "    ],\n" +
           "    \"analyzer\": \"standard\"\n" +
           "  }\n" +
           "}")
   @Highlight(
           fields = @HighlightField(
                   name = "['code','name']"),
           parameters = @HighlightParameters(
                   preTags = "<strong>",
                   postTags = "</strong>",
                   fragmentSize = 500,
                   numberOfFragments = 3
           )
   )
   List<CodeNames> findAllByCodeAndNameOrderByName(String code, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the specify each highlight field in a separate annotation argument:

```
   @Query("{\n" +
            "  \"multi_match\": {\n" +
            "    \"query\": \"?0\",\n" +
            "    \"fields\": [\n" +
            "      \"code^2\",\n" +
            "      \"name\"\n" +
            "    ],\n" +
            "    \"analyzer\": \"standard\"\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}")
    @Highlight(
        fields = {
            @HighlightField(name = "code"),
            @HighlightField(name = "name")
        },
        parameters = @HighlightParameters(
            preTags = "<strong>",
            postTags = "</strong>",
            fragmentSize = 500,
            numberOfFragments = 3
        )
    )
    List<CodeNames> findAllByCodeAndNameOrderByName(String code, Pageable pageable);
```

Edit:

In addition to that you have to change the return type of your method:

```
List<SearchHit<CodeNames>> findAllByCodeAndNameOrderByName(String code, Pageable pageable);
```

or

```
SearchHits<CodeNames> findAllByCodeAndNameOrderByName(String code, Pageable pageable);
```

to be able to read the highlight values from the returned `SearchHit`, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.0.RC2/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations.searchresulttypes

Comment: Thank you!
how do i get the highlighted values into the Document object CodeNames, here is my POJO:
atDocument(indexName = "indextest", type = "_doc")
public class CodeNames {
    atId
    private String id;

    private String code;

    private String name;

    private String highlight;

    public String  getHighlight() {
        return highlight;
    }

    public void setHighlight(String highlight) {
        this.highlight = highlight;
    }
...

Comment: As RC2 has dependency on Spring boot 2.3, i may not use RC2.
I'm using Spring boot 2.2.6
How to add query level subqueries in the @Query, can i get highlight field values, without using highlight annotation, 
eg: can i use some thing like this
@Query("{\"multi_match\":{\"query\":\"?0\",\"fields\":[\"code^2\",\"name\"],\"analyzer\":\"standard\"}},{\"highlight\":{\"type\":\"plain\",\"fields\":{\"*\":{}}}}")

Comment: Spring Boot 2.3 will be released next thursday. SDE 4.0 should come on Tuesday. You cannot add highlighting to `@Query`, you would need to construct a `NativeSearchQuery` in your programcode. And you'd need to do your custom parsing of the whole response with a `ResultsExtractor`

Comment: I'm testing sde 4. it does give the highlighte fields in the results with List<SearchHit<CodeNames>>, but it also comes with score,sortValues, etc., 
how can i only have the highlight fields and not the other searhit values, with out writing a java value object.

Comment: You get a `SearchHit` object that contains the entity along with other information. What's the problem with additional information being in the `SearchHit`?

Comment: There is no problem, i wanted to trim and get only the necessary fields from SearchHit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer on HIghlight query
I've created a new question on sort, can you take a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805654/how-to-store-distance-value-to-sortvalues-or-entity