# How to Store Distance value to SortValues or Entity

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to Store Distance value to SortValues or Entity using SDE4.0 @Query, and SearchHit

```
"sort": [
  {
    "_geo_distance" : {
      "codenames.geoLocation" : [
        {
          "lat" : 32.846027,
          "lon" : -96.84987
        }
      ],
      "unit" : "mi",
      "order" : "asc",
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a `Sort` parameter t your repository query, see [the documentation for Spring Data Elasticsearch 4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.misc.sorts) where this is described.

In your case you'd need:

```
Sort sort = Sort.by(
    new GeoDistanceOrder("geoLocation", new GeoPoint(32.846027, -96.84987))
        .withUnit("mi")
        .with(Sort.Direction.ASC)
);
```

you can leave out the sort direction, because ASC is the default value

Comment: @P.J.Meish Thank you, it worked 

---
 "sortValues": [
            19.18168812294621
        ]